# add functionality to Create method

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

Good day for everyone. As says in title, i want to add some logic to Ext.create method but  i dont understand how to do it. What do you think about it and Maybe it's bad way and you have another approach. Thanks for answering

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: What research you have done LALALALALALA ?

Answer (score 1):

For those who really want to override [Ext.create](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext-method-create):

```
Ext.create = (function(){
    var original = Ext.create;
    return function() {
        // custom logic
        // call the original Ext.create()
        return original.apply(Ext, arguments);
    };
})();
//created by Renku
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to override the `Ext.create` function you can simply

```
Ext.create = function() {
    // your new logic here
}
```

**Note:** If you do this, the original implementation of the method is lost, so you have to provide logic that includes the default behaviour for the `Ext` components to still work.

If it is a good idea depends on what it is that you are going to do. But I doubt it is really necessary and probably there is a better way - but as said, that depends and can not be said given the information in your post.